# kvm custom scripts for automation of pci device attachment

Tags: kvm

Can anyone help me in two things:

- my kvm server is in my lan. How to use virsh to create and manage my guest vm in my host,
- can any one write me a shell script that when the device id is given attaches it to my guest.

If I want to attach my

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Curacao XT [Radeon R9 270X] [1002:6810]
```

I give `01:00.0 <vm_name>` as parameter to my script and it will attach my corresponding pci device to my vm.